# pythonでwhileループなどを使って平均計算の出力をする方法は？

Tags: python, python3

1行ごとに整数が入力され、最後の行がピリオド.で終了するとします。そして、入力された数の平均を計算して出力したいと思っています。イメージとしては、このように入力されたとします

```
5 
2 
10 
1
.
```

それをこのように出力したいのです

```
4.5
```

このようなコードを書きました。

```
num = input()
res = []
while num != ".":
    res.appen(num)
    if num = ".":
        break
    print(mean(res))
```

その結果このようなエラーメッセージを受け取りました。

```
Error:
  File "jailed_code", line 5
    if num = ".":
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

この場合、5行目が問題なのは明らかなのですが、それ以外にも問題があるかもしれません。どのようにすれば改善すれば良いでしょうか。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 丁寧な回答をありがとうございました。大変勉強になりました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

質問の直接の答えは`比較演算子が違う`からです。以下2つの記事を良く見てください。
問題の箇所は`==`が正しく、つまり`=`が一つ足らないことが原因です。

[4.1. if 文](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements)
[6.10. 比較](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons)

---

他にはこれらの課題があります。

- 数値を入力できるのが先頭行の1回だけで、複数の数値を繰り返し入力出来るようになっていません。ループの中(の先頭)に移動する必要があるでしょう。
- `while`の条件部と、途中の`if`文の両方でループ終了を判定するのは冗長で間違いやすいので判定は1ヵ所に絞りましょう。
- `appen()`というメソッドはありません。`append()`のtypoですね。
- 最後の`.`を入力したら、結果を出力せずにプログラムを終了する形になっています。
- `mean()`メソッドは`statistics`を`import`しないと使えるようにはなりません。
- `mean()`メソッドは数値の平均を計算するものなので、`res`リストには文字列ではなくintの数値が入っていなければなりません。
  `res`に`append`する際に`int`に変換しておくか、`mean`を計算する際または直前に`int`に変換する必要があります。
- 数値を繰り返し入力出来るようになったとしても今の`print(mean(res))`の位置では数値を入力する毎に平均値を表示することになります。平均値表示の処理はどこで行うのが良いか考え直してください。

[5.1. リスト型についてもう少し](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)

> list.append(x)
> 　リストの末尾に要素を一つ追加します。a[len(a):] = [x] と等価です。

[statistics --- 数理統計関数](https://docs.python.org/ja/3.9/library/statistics.html)
[Pythonで平均、中央値、最頻値、分散、標準偏差を算出](https://note.nkmk.me/python-statistics-mean-median-mode-var-stdev/)

[数値型 int, float, complex](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex)

> 演算　　結果
> int(x)　x の整数への変換

---

`mean`を使わずに済ませるなら、直接の答えは提示していませんが、こんな記事もあります。
[無限ループからの平均値を出したい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/70598/26370)

Answer (score 1):

> それ以外にも問題があるかもしれません。どのようにすれば改善すれば良いでしょうか。

`input()` を使用する場合、`EOF(End of File)` を検出すると `EOFError` が発生します。以下の様に `iteration` を利用すれば `EOF` で for loop が自動的に停止します。

[7.2.1. Methods of File Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects)

> For reading lines from a file, you can loop over the file object. This is memory efficient, fast, and leads to simple code:
>
> ```
> >>> for line in f:
> ...     print(line, end='')
> ...
> ```

また、入力文字列を数値への変換する場合にエラーになる場合(非数値な文字列を入力する)を考慮して例外処理を追加します。その他に、入力値が全くない(最初に `.` を入力してしまう)場合に `ZeroDivisionError` が発生してしまいますので、`res` リストの要素数をチェックします。

※ 以下、walrus operator(`:=`, セイウチ演算子)を使っていますので Python 3.8 以降でのみ動作します

**mean.py**

```py
import sys

res = []
for num in sys.stdin:
  num = num.strip()
  if num == '.': break
  try:
    n = float(num)
  except ValueError as e:
    print(e, file=sys.stderr)
    sys.exit(1)
  res.append(n)

if (l := len(res)) > 0:
  mean = sum(res)/l
  print(f'{mean = }')
else:
  print('there is no numbers', file=sys.stderr)
```

Python3 における `float`型には表現可能な数値に最小値・最大値が存在します(`int`型にはなし)。

```sh
$ python3 --version
Python 3.9.5

$ python3 -c 'import sys;print(sys.float_info)'
sys.float_info(max=1.7976931348623157e+308, max_exp=1024,
max_10_exp=308, min=2.2250738585072014e-308, min_exp=-1021,
min_10_exp=-307, dig=15, mant_dig=53, epsilon=2.220446049250313e-16, radix=2, rounds=1)
```

したがって、計算結果にオーバーフローが発生する可能性があるのですが、実際には `inf`(infinity) が返ります。

```sh
$ python3 mean.py
1e+500
1e+1000
.
mean = inf
```